# Convert uint32 to string and add leading 0s

Tags: string, go, uint32, leading-zero

I need to convert uint32 to a string and add leading zeroes to a fixed length. How can I do that?

Here's my code:

```
var unixTs uint32 = 1446455472
var randomInt uint32 = 58964981
var expiredTs uint32 = 2

unixTsStr := fmt.Sprint("%010d", unixTs)
randomIntStr := fmt.Sprint("%08d", randomInt)
expiredTsStr := fmt.Sprint("%010d", expiredTs)
```

Output prints:

```
%010d1446455472
%08d58964981
%010d2
```

What I want is:

```
1446455472
58964981
0000000002
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [fmt.Sprintf](http://godoc.org/fmt#Sprintf) instead of [fmt.Sprint](http://godoc.org/fmt#Sprint).  Sprintf formats according to a format specifier. Sprint formats using the default format for each argument.

<kbd>[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/hQIcgRO7EY)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, that did it! I will check off the answer in 10 mins :)